# magento2 module frontend - Change downloadable links

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, downloadable

With Magento2 **template path hints** turned on, (custom theme inherited from luma) I have been able to locate that  want to change some of the code in the area where the downloadable links are shown on a product details page of a downloadable item.

(really I want to hide that on the storefront, and only show to customer on purchase) - as it's pushing the add to cart button way down the page, etc.

From the template path hints, I have located I want to edit:

```
vendor > magento > module-downloadable > frontend > templates > catalog > product > links.phtml
```

so I thought that I could create a similar structure in my:

```
app > design > frontend > MYVENDOR > MYTHEME
```

directory, but it's not working, no matter what, so I am thinking I am not necessarily doing it right. If I could see an example of how to accomplish this, I should be able to figure out others on my own :) thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution that worked is for the path to be:

```
app > design > frontend > MYVENDOR > MYTHEME > Magento_Downloadable > templates > catalog > product > links.phtml
```

so no "frontend" subfolder UNDER the theme...

Answer (score 0):

You should copy file to app > design > frontend > MYVENDOR > MYTHEME > Magento_Downloadable > frontend > templates > catalog > product > links.phtml and modify it

Comment: thank you for the reply, I did that exactly, flushed everything caches, etc. didnt work... after doing that and turning template path hints back on, it shows: public_html/vendor/magento/module-downloadable/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/links.phtml

Comment: Did you switch to new theme, delete pub/static/frontend/* and run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy:?

Comment: I did and now I found the solution, answer below: